# Application update changes the /Library path

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, core-data-migration, nsdocumentdirectory

I have a problem with application update. In the version 1.0 I had large number of files downloaded and path to those files are persisted in coredata as a attribute on object.
for example: `/var/mobile/Applications/43543f-435435-etc.../Library/folder/image.png`

After I try to test update with testflight or installing version 1.1 with iTunes, the path

`NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *applicationDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];`

now returns different, something like

`/var/mobile/Application/324dfd-325dfd..etc/`

And my application fails to show all the images and data, since I pull down the path saved on the coredata object.
But what surprises me the most is, when I install the version 1.1 directly from xcode, it works good, and nothing is changed. What should I do? Should I crate a upgrade script to change the Library path for the each file in coredata or is there a better way ?

Thank you

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense.  You are searching for `NSLibraryDirectory` yet you assign it to `applicationDirectory` which looks suspicious.

Comment: applicationDirectory is just a variable name i use later on in the system.

Comment: I assume the issue is elsewhere else there would be 100s of questions like this on here and this is the first I've seen of it.  I think we will need to see more code where `applicationDirectory` is being used.

Comment: the /var/mobile/Applications/bla-bla-bla/Library is the applicationDirectory variable. and it changes the "bla-bla-bla" part on update when I install .ipa with iTunes or TestFlight, but it doesn't update when I install the updated version with xcode. That leaves me thinking, should I or not do a migration of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are storing the *full path* to the file within the Core Data object.  You should be storing a *relative path* from the `Library` folder, which you retrieved using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()`.

This will mean you have to create the full path at runtime using the Library folder plus the relative element retrieved from Core Data.

This will then survive an app upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I am storing a full path.. So I'm thinking what's the best option to do now

Comment: Store the relative path.